# Сборка jar + proguard в gradle

Tags: java, gradle

У меня есть проект со сторонними библиотеками. В один прекрасный момент я решил подключить к нему оптимизатор ProGuard. Как я понял, что отдавать ProGuard'у давать jar со всеми зависимыми библиотеками внутри не очень круто (вылетают кучи ошибок).

Я решил идти таким путём:

1. Собрать мои классы в jar
2. Дать ProGuard'у jar из предыдущего пункта
3. Результат слить со всеми зависимыми библиотеками.

Сейчас в gradle.build:

```
group 'Alex_P'
version '3.0.0-PRE'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir dirs: '.'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':proguard:'
    }
}

task assembleSingleJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': project.name,
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'ru.alexp.gc.FileManager'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': project.name,
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': "ru.alexp.gc.FileManager"
    }
}

task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguard.cfg'

    injars 'build/libs/FileManager-all-3.0.0-PRE.jar'
    outjars 'build/libs/FileManager-all-3.0.0-PRE-PRO.jar'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.json:json:20151123'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: а в чём состоит вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

> отдавать ProGuard'у давать jar со всеми зависимыми библиотеками внутри не очень круто.

По моему, лучше как раз отдавать ему jar с зависимыми библиотеками. Тогда файл получется более оптимизированным - меньшего размера.

ProGuard уменьшает размер файла путем переименования классов/методов/полей. Например был класс `MyClass` стал `a`. Отдашь ему зависимые библиотеки, он в них классы тоже переименует.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, но у меня не хватает каких-то библиотек для log4j.
У меня сейчас из сторонних: log4j-core, log4j-api, json.
Что мне надо ещё подключить чтобы PG не орал на l4j.
Пример:
    Warning: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Activator: can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle
   Warning: there were 1007 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

Comment: Full: http://pastebin.com/YD5Q7bUH